# What can you pass into the parameter map for CommunityService.getMyCommunities?

Tags: ibm-sbt

I want to get a particular IBM Connections community by Name using IBM Social Business Toolkit Java API

I see getMyCommunities() has an argument for parameters but can't find any docs to explain what those params can be.

Does anyone know what parameters are supported?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the parameter [listed here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Connections%204.5%20API%20Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Getting_the_My_Communities_feed_ic45&content=pdcontent); look in table 2, it will provide the parameter names and the expected values along with their effects